# Footer will not stay down

Tags: php, css, opencart, footer, sticky

I have tried SO MANY DIFFERENT THINGS and I cannot get my footer to stay at the bottom.

Using Opencart makes it a little more difficult for me to find where the issue is but I JUST CANNOT FIGURE OUT WHY.

The link below shows where the issue is replicated. However, when there is minimal content on ANY page, the issue appears. So technically, since the footer shows on all pages (as a common file) it's a persistent problem.

http://shop.enigmedesigns.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=17

I'm at the end of my rope. Could someone take a look through the code and see any potential issues? Solutions? Why won't my footer just stay down?

edit: Footer code...

```
<div id="footerwrapper">
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="links">
        <ul>
         <li><?php echo $text_copyright; ?></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $about; ?>"><?php echo $text_about; ?></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $privacy; ?>"><?php echo $text_privacy; ?></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $terms; ?>"><?php echo $text_terms; ?></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $affiliate; ?>"><?php echo $text_affiliate; ?></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

edit: There is a large amount of white space below the footer on pages with little content. I am not looking for the footer to scroll with the page so a fixed position is not an option. I'm trying to remove the white space and have the footer remain at the bottom.

Comment: `<?php echo $home.'"'.$text_home; ?>` it will do the same so you can just save time

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Thanks! That'll shave off some space in a ton of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the footer to stick to the bottom of the screen when there is not enough content to fill the screen, but not overlap the content if there is enough content for it to scroll, try https://code.google.com/p/cleanstickyfooter/.

Comment: The background now stretches 100%. YAY! And the footer is down at the bottom (no scrolling issues), but I can't get the "content" div to stretch all the way down. Not an issue with filled pages but empty pages... Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
#footerwrapper {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; left: 0
}
```

From W3Schools:

> An element with fixed position
>   is positioned relative to the browser window.

It will not move even if the window is scrolled

Comment: Will that stick the footer to the bottom of the screen (not the page) even if the page is scrolled to the very top?

Comment: Yes it fixes the element at the bottom of the window

Comment: @RoyMJ I am attempting to keep it at the bottom of all of the preceding content (removing the whitespace below the footer), not at the bottom of the visible screen.

Comment: @user1566238 : So when you scroll up, the footer wont be visible then... I'm thinking thats how your code worked..

Comment: @RoyMJ Right now, the footer doesn't move when you scroll, but there is a very large white area BELOW the footer when scrolled all the way to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your problem by adding below line of code to you css.

```
#footerwrapper { position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; }
```

Comment: I want the footer to sit at the bottom of the page, but I don't want the footer to scroll with the page. There's a large amount of white space below the footer like the "container" isn't stretching to the whole height of the page.